# How to configure logging in docker-compose YAML using environment variables?

Tags: docker-compose

I am working with a single Docker Compose YAML configuration that works for a variety of environments by using environment variables, aka `${MYENV-default}`. However, I've found that the `logging:` section does not allow this kind of substitution in the logging option *names*.

```
    logging:
      # this works:
      driver: ${LOGDRIVER-local}
      options:
        # this does NOT work:
        ${LOGOPT1_NAME-max-size}: ${LOGOPT1_VALUE-10m}
        ${LOGOPT2_NAME-max-file}: ${LOGOPT2_VALUE-3}
```

Is there a way to make these configurable via environment variables or some other means such that the YAML does not have to be modified depending on what logging driver is to be enabled?

(Docker Compose version v2.14.1)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple compose files is probably my best bet: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files

> Using multiple Compose files enables you to customize a Compose application for different environments or different workflows.

I can add a secondary YAML which defines the logging and then merge them together when running:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f logging.yaml up
```